# Android dialog - changing data

Tags: android, layout, view, android-activity, dialog

I have MainActivity where I've got a button which opens a dialog. Once I click this button, I have my dialog frame opened, and now I have two text fields in this dialog and two buttons.

How do I change the text in that field by clicking one of those buttons?

I was trying some tricks, but I've always got `NullPointerException`.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I would use a custom dialog.

You need to use dialog object to findViewById and initialize views.

dialog.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="58dp"
        android:text="Cancel" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/ed1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button2"
          />

    <EditText
          android:id="@+id/ed2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_marginRight="27dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="39dp"
        android:text="ChangeText" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Then in your activity say on button click

```
 dialogPopup();
```

Then

```
public void dialogPopup()
{
    final Dialog d = new Dialog(MainActivity.this); // initialize dialog
    d.setContentView( R.layout.dialog);
    d.setTitle("my title");
    final EdiText ed1= (TextView) d.findViewById(R.id.ed1);
    // initialize edittext using the dialog object. 
    final EdiText ed2= (TextView) d.findViewById(R.id.ed2);
    Button b = (Button) d.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() // button 1 click
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    // on click of button 1 change the text in textview's
            ed1.setText("Changing text 1");
            ed2.setText("Changing text 2");
        }

    });
     Button b1 = (Button) d.findViewById(R.id.button2); // button2 click
        b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                d.dismiss(); // dismiss dialog
            }

        });
        d.show(); // show the dialog
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you create the dialog with AlertDialog.Builder, set the Button's onClickListener to change the EditText's value:

```
AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builer(this);
...
final EditText edit = new EditText(this);
dialog.setView(edit);
...
dialog.setPositiveButton("Change the freakin text",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id){
                    edit.setText("bla bla bla");
                }
              });
...
```

Comment: But I have already created EditText field with random text, and i want to change it by clicking a button. How to get ID of this EditText field which is placed in Dialog layout ?

Comment: You already have the EditText's reference, because you created it programatically before adding it to the Dialog. If you have not created it programatically, but in an XML layout, then use `findViewById(id)` where id is its name in the layout.

Comment: @dejvid you need to use dialog object to initialize the editext. you can `findViewById` of the current view hierarchy set to the activity. In your case you have dialog. So you need to use dialog object to initalize edittext.

Comment: @dejvid check my edit. it should work. modify according to your needs